# Performance monitor of digest cycle execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, digest

I have an app, that is very slow on low end PCs, and I just downloaded Batarang to monitor performance.

On an empty page, that only has a header and a sidebar, I see this:
[image]

Meaning, the cycle is constantly running. I don't know why, since I am just watching the page, not clicking a thing, not moving a thing.

And in a different AngularJS app (not mine), I see this:
[image]

When not changing a thing, a digest is running every 20-30 seconds.

Why can a thing like this happen? Is there a way to check which watchers fired the digest cycle?

**EDIT:**

Is there a way to print all dirty watchers, and see what is the expression that is dirty?

I printed a random watcher:

`JSON.stringify(getWatchers()[2])
"{"last":3,"eq":false}"`

It does not say the expression

Comment: check if you have a $timeout somewhere, also debug all $rootScope.apply calls

Comment: It looks like the second chart us running every 30 seconds because it takes 30 seconds to finish.

Comment: @pgreen2 no.. it finishes, otherwise it will keep showing it

Comment: We have no way to know what is going on without some code context

Comment: Set up a breakpoint on [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ng/rootScope.js#L755) and watch for call stack. It is as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

Digest cycle is being run on all triggered changes in scope and on all changes that were caused by previous digest cycle, until there will be no changes detected.

Ex.
There is a click handler in controller where you change some value, than this change might be watched somewhere else, so digest will be run again.

Comment: OK, is there a way to see what was changed? I printed all watchers with 'eq' false, but it does not say the expression